# Where is Keying feature in Blender 2.93

Tags: animation, dopesheet

Im' following tutorial in some older Blender version in which you can select Active Keying Set to Available and then where is Auto Keyframming select this icon next to the cursor on picture to prevent Blender from adding unnecesarry keyframes while in Auto Keying mode. In my Blender 2.93 it's not there anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These option were transported here:
[image]

Comment: Ty, this is now "Only Active Keying Set"? What about Layered Recording?

Comment: I am sorry I am not using this feature so I don't know, hopefully someone else will know